# IE9 strips comma from translate(123,456) SVG markup

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

Observed: IE9 strips comma character from incoming SVG `<g transform="translate(123,456)">` markup.  Just thought I'd throw the observation out here in case is bites anyone trying to provide Javascript client-side mods to the SVG DOM.  This seems kind of wierd since comma is supported in the W3C standard.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I realize this is not a question per se, but I was just trying to pass along what appeared to be a correctly observed condition that can mess-up your code.

Comment: It also strips them from path attributes if the path begins with, e.g. an "M" like so: d="M662.846,146.9[...]". This is true when parsing as an XML document, too.

Comment: If IE9 or IE10 removes the commas from an SVG path (replaces commas with spaces, actually), here's a regex to replace them:
`str.replace( /([^a-z])\s([^\-a-z])/gi, '$1,$2' );`

Comment: Why closed??? This is an extremely valid issue! The only mistake is that is not formulated as a question.

Comment: Hi @tilda, yes I submitted this in order to share out a "watch out for" type thing, or if folks had ideas about the root cause or work arounds.  I didn't know Stackoverflow was locked into "ask a question" mode.  But it's all good, this item is out there and searchable.